# Setup live magento 1.7 to local server

Tags: magento-1.7

I m trying to setup magento live site to local system. I also gone through various forum, and tried all suggested solution but still I m not able to enter admin section.

I have modified the varian.php file as suggested, cleared the cache files under var and purged my browser but still can not log in to admin panel. It gives the following url

http://praveen.linuxstagedb.com/poppyshop/index.php/spsitemanager/dashboard/index/key/4d80fdfbf3d9f40ab36ac79a25fb12ab/

Note - spsitemanager used for admin.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks
Praveen Shukla

Comment: are you trying to make your local site available on internet? It means, if you type your site address from any where over the internet it has to get access... Is this what are you trying for? or is there any other requirement?

Comment: Hi Pavan, thanks for your consideration. I m trying to setup live site back into our local system for some maintenance work. Can you Please help me that why I m not able to enter admin section?

Comment: First let me know, why you have modified the varien.php file?. It is a core file and it does nothing for your requirement. and also which browser you are using? If it is chrome, then it is due to the cookies. Try in different browser like firefox or opera

Comment: Hi Pavan, I m using firefox. As per different forum and site I updated the varien.php (http://www.phpgenious.com/2010/02/cant-login-into-admin-panel-of-magento-problem-and-solution/).

Comment: can you post the code that you changed in varien.php file?

Comment: I m using clone back up live site and there are 2 files local.xml.dev and local.xml.live in app\etc. I modified local.xml.dev as local.xml and update the db information.I m using host as localhost. There are also active_directory_admin_login and memcached tag in local.xml.Can i remove it?

Comment: // session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
//'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
//'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
//'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
/*
if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
unset($cookieParams['secure']);
if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
unset($cookieParams['domain']);
}           }
        }


        if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
            $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
        }
  */

Comment: See here is your mistake.. You have commented the required code also. Check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the code that you have commented in that file and paste the below code in the same area.

```
 // session cookie params
        $cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
            //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
            //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
    if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
        unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
        if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
            unset($cookieParams['secure']);
            if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
                unset($cookieParams['domain']);
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
        $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
    }
```

Comment: Did u try removing index.php from the url that u placed in the question and reloading the page..

Comment: I have dump of live site and database.I updated local.xml.dev as local.xml and change the <connection> tage for db. If anything else I forgot to update, Please let me know.

Comment: Hi Pavan - there was problem related to memory_limit that's why database connection were break.

Comment: Can you please tell what things we need to change or modified from admin section so that frontend design and layout will work perfectly.

Comment: Now are you able to login into the admin? and what is the issue that you are facing with the frontend design? place a snapshot of it

Comment: Yes I m able to login in admin.I mean to that Is there anything we need to add/update like any configuration, design, theme and Templates. actually we setup live site dump in local system.Can you please guide me that what necessary things to be done through admin section so that local site display as live site.

Comment: If you are taking a dump of database and code of live site and implementing in it locally, then automatically it has to behave as live site only. Are u seeing it any different now?

Comment: Actually, we are not able to get images of products. We get error - 1.Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in /home/Praveen/public_html/poppyshop/app/design/frontend/Screenpages/default/template/page/html/pager.phtml on line 34 2.File does not exist: /home/Praveen/public_html/poppyshop/skin/adminhtml/base/default/donation.css

Comment: we also see there is a image with path - http://poppyshop-stage.wearecargo.com/media/wysiwyg/category-banners/banner_christmas.jpg but in site folder we did not get any wysiwyg folder inside media.

Comment: in which page you are getting this error? I just visited your site? It doesnt show any image but page loads fine. Give me the link of the page you get this error?

Comment: Hi Pavan I need your help. I got error on page - Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in /home/Praveen/public_html/poppyshop/app/design/frontend/Screenpages/default/template/page/html/pager.phtml on line 34. The theme name is Screenpages.Can you please help me for this.